# Angular4/5: Find whether the tab is active or not

Tags: angular

I am trying to check whether my application's tab is active on the browser or not but couldn't able to proceed. I am implementing the application in angular5

Answer (score 0):

Page Visibility API can let users know whether a webpage is on focus or visible.  Use the visibilitychange property.  This is from pure javascript so you can implement in Angular 4/5.